# How to do a factory reset on a SanDisk Cruzer Blade flash drive?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, flashing

I have a 8 GB Sandisk USB flash drive. Recently it became write protected somehow. So I searched in Google and I tried to remove the write protection through almost all the methods I found. Unfortunately nothing worked.

So I decided to try some other ways. Some said that flashing the USB flash drive will solve the problem. But I don't know how. So how can it be done ? What I meant by flashing is to repair the USB flash drive by softwaring it again. Or, is there any way to do a factory reset to it ?

Comment: Your drive became _writeable_? Or _read-only_?

Comment: @summea Write protected actually.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please rephraise your question so what you want to know is crystal clar.  Update your question its a living breathing question.

Comment: After you back up your files on the USB drive, have you tried reformatting the drive?

Comment: @summea Yeah. Several times. Formatting won't happen in it. When ever I tried to format, it says 'The USB flash drive is write protected'.

Comment: Ah; sometimes companies make some sort of application to do more of a "factory reset" for flash drives (or memory cards) but I haven't been able to find something like that for SanDisk _(at the moment, at least.)_ Does anything on [this other thread](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/296309-32-remove-write-protection-sandisk-cruzer-flash-drive) help? It may be time to invest in a new flash drive, too...

Comment: Could this be a case of the drive reaching the end of it's life and locking itself?  Flash devices have limited write cycles, a well designed one will go read only when it's out of anticipated life to avoid losing data when a cell actually fails.

Comment: @summea I already tried that.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Are you saying that its time to buy a new one ?

Comment: Yes, he is saying that.

Comment: Did you try reformatting it in Windows Disk Management?

Comment: @AdmiralAdama Yes, I did. Can you help me ?

Comment: @LorenPechtel You said that flash drives have write cycles. Is it possible to reset it ?

Comment: @Tom: You wouldn't want to.  The write counter is a safety device--it's much better to have the drive go read only than corrupt data when the cell burns out.